# Is it possible to combine multiple internet connections (eg wifi access points) for better performance

Tags: wireless-networking, internet-connection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Connect multiple WiFi networks simultaneously](https://superuser.com/questions/139980/connect-multiple-wifi-networks-simultaneously)

I would like to make use of multiple internet connections over wifi (specifically two Android phones with wifi tethering enabled, not hacking my neighbours' wifi!) on my Windows 7 PC. Or in other words, combine or aggregate two internet connections for better performance.
I'm not a heavy user so decided to save money avoiding a wired ISP connection. Mobile internet is ok, but it would be nice to double it :)

Ideally it would result in a single virtual connection that routes the internet requests (eg from browser) through both connections. I guess it's not possible to split a TCP request over two connections, but it would still be nice if every second request alternated between connections, which would be idea for loading a page with lots of images.

Comment: So what I think I'm asking is for Link Aggregation without additional hardware, but would also be happy with Load Balancing (again without additional hardware)

Comment: Note a duplicate, he is referring to interface bonding/aggregation, which is roughly the opposite of the other question.

Comment: At a minimum, you'd need two WiFi interfaces in your computer or router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process that you're referring to is usually referred to as **network bonding.** Possible? yes. Practical? Eh...

First off, you're almost certainly going to need hardware for this. I am not aware of any pure software solution that works across devices (i.e. isn't specific to ethernet or 802.11g).

Second, the hardware solutions are very expensive: Mushroom Networks, MiniCaster, etc all make boxes that run $1500+.